# How to get first n charakters of a string AND the last one?

Tags: python, string, slice, encode

I got this code which does something with the first 10 charakters of a string:

`f_binary = f.encode(encoding='utf_8')[0:10]`

but I want to do it with the 19th charakter as well.  I tried like this:

`f_binary = f.encode(encoding='utf_8')[0:10],[19]`

and this:

`f_binary = f.encode(encoding='utf_8')[0:10,19]` but it doesn't work.

Python's list comprehension doesn't help me either because it doesn't show how to deal with a larger and a small part of a list or string at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
f_binary = (f[0:10]+f[-1]).encode(encoding='utf_8')
```

to encode the first 10 and the last character of string `f`

Comment: doesn't work because it's already in a for loop: ```for f in my_list: f_binary = f.encode(encoding='utf_8')[0:10]```

Comment: @WamboRambo so how does that make a difference?

Comment: I get the error ```TypeError: can't concat int to bytes```

Comment: Do you need the 19th character of the string, or the byte object?

Comment: Well, each ```f``` is a string of 19 charakters in a list. And I need to encode the first 10 as well as the last digit of each ```f``` so yeah, the 19th charakter

Answer (score 0):

turn it to a string and then select using

`first_n_chars_and_last = (f[0:n], f[-1])`

and turn it THEN into a bytes object

Comment: Thank you, that lead me to the solution - but I found out I had to do ```(f[0:10]+ f[-1])``` instead of your suggestion.